# Counterexample: $A$ open and $A \subset cl(B) $ but $ A \not\subset B$

Tags: general-topology

I was reading a proof of the open mapping theorem, where the last step is a fairly complicated proof that with the closure of a particular set containing an open ball then so too does the set itself.

Intuitively it appeared (to me at least) that in general with $A$ open and $A \subset cl(B)  $ it should follow that $ A \subset B$. Certainly being open, then $A \subset int(cl(B))$ and one might think that $int(cl(B)) \subset B$.

Since I couldn't prove this, and assume that if it were true then it would have been referenced in the open mapping proof, I looked for a counterexample. **I'd appreciate feedback on the following construction (or a more suitable example if available).**

Define a topological space with $X = $ the points of the closed unit disk in a plane and the topology $\mathscr T =$ the discrete topology (i.e. all subsets of X).

Let $D$ be the open unit disk, then $cl(D) = X$ and so $X \subset cl(D)$. But in any topology $X$ itself is an open (and closed ) set and clearly $X \not \subset D$.

---

Thanks for feedback. It appears my example is incorrect, but there are two correct examples in the comments and answer

Comment: In a discrete topology, $cl(B)=B$ for all subsets $B$ (because all sets are closed as well as open), which means that if you have $A\subset cl(B)$, you also have $A\subset B$.

Comment: Let $X$ be any topological space and $D$ a proper dense subset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A = \mathbb{R}, B = \mathbb{Q}$, then $A \subseteq cl(B) = \mathbb{R}$, but obviously $A \not \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

A more subtle example:

Let $(a_n)$ be an ennumeration of the rationals.

Set $A=\bigcup_{i \ge 1} I_i$ where $I_i$ is an interval centered at $a_i$ with length $c \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i$ and $c$ any positive number.

$B=\mathbb{I}$, the irrationals.

$A$ is open and does not contain all the irrationals
(what can you say about the measure ("length") of $A$?). Moreover $cl(A)=cl(B)$.